# Object appears bright even when there is no light

Tags: game-engine, camera, light

I was trying to integrate a dragon model from blendswap into my model, but the problem is that no matter what I do the dragon appears bright and is fully visible. Can someone help me understand what is the source of light which is causing the dragon to appear rather than look similar to objects on the map (for instance the building)

Here is the [blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tlu7id4jr2wx50l/dragon%20-%20Copy.blend?dl=0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the dragon's texture is influencing the *Emit* property of the material. If you disable it in *Properties > Textures > Influence* (with the dragon selected), it works as expected:

[image]